# PayPal JavaScript SDK: How to change the 'Buy Now' button to 'Pay Now'?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm using the latest version of PayPal JavaScript SDK (instead of the deprecated `checkout.js`) together with the **Smart Button** for my payment page. When PayPal shows the credit/debit card data entry form, at the bottom, I want it to display **'Pay Now'** instead of **'Buy Now'**, how can I do that?

I [followed this example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#style), but it only changes the main button with **'Pay with PayPal'** together with the 'Credit/Debit Card' button, but the blue color 'Buy Now' still showing below the form:

```
paypal.Buttons({
  style: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    color:  'gold',
    shape:  'rect',
    label:  'pay' // I changed to 'pay' instead
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I even [follow this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-configuration/#commit) to add the `commit=true` parameter to the SDK but no luck:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&commit=true"></script>
```

Below is my full code just in case you need it:

```
            paypal.Buttons({
                style: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    color: 'gold',
                    shape: 'rect',
                    label: "pay"
                },
                createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                    // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                    return actions.order.create({
                        purchase_units: [{
                            amount: {
                                currency_code: "MYR",
                                value: "1.00"
                            }
                        }],
                        application_context: {
                            shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
                        }
                    });
                },
                onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                    return actions.order.capture()
                        .then(function (details) {
                            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                        });
                }
            }).render('#gPayContainer');
            //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: " but the blue color 'Buy Now' still showing below the form:" -- what do you mean?

Comment: I want the blue color 'Buy Now' button to change to 'Pay Now'.

Comment: Which blue color 'Buy Now' button? .......

Comment: I've already explained in my question, right below the credit card data entry form.

Comment: Everything says Pay Now. But if you are speaking of the Pay Now button inside the expanded Debit or Credit Card form, there is no way to change it regardless. It will always say whatever that locale translates for Pay Now.

Comment: "In most cases, you use the Buy Now button for selling merchandise and the Pay Now button for selling services." -- [PayPal Doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buy-now-step-1/)

Comment: PayPal Payments Standard ( non-smart buttons at https://www.paypal.com/buttons ) have nothing to do with the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Yes, nothing to do with SDK or even PayPal Payments Standard -- Just a quote from PayPal that emphasizes the difference between Pay Now and Buy Now. I was referring to your statement: "It will always say whatever that locale translates for Pay Now." By the way, the locale translation in Malaysia for Pay Now is "Bayar Sekarang", not Pay Now being translated to Buy Now. Your argument doesn't make sense. If it cannot be done, just say cannot be done, don't say something that is not exist.

Comment: In saying "It will always say..." I'm referring to the JavaScript SDK experience, which always says "Pay Now" with `label: pay`, and inside the form will always say "Pay Now" regardless of the label setting for the presented buttons..  I don't know what behavior you are complaining about or asking to be different, since it doesn't exist. If the Malay locale translates the button's "Pay Now" text string differently than what you expect or desire, then you are complaining of a translation issue or choice on a site outside your control (iframed), which is not a technical problem for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @Preston PHX commented, whether **Pay Now** or **Buy Now**, it's by **locale** translated by PayPal. Take a look at the screenshot below, if England is selected (by default), the button text is **Buy Now**:

[image]

However, when **Malaysia** is selected (and only AFTER the country selection dropdown list is losing the focus), the button text changes to **Pay Now**:

[image]

We do not know why PayPal translates in this way and the necessity behind it because:

1. The Malaysian English is in fact following the British English standard since the day it was colonized by British and even after the independence day.
2. **Pay Now** and **Buy Now** are both English but serves different meaning.
3. For **Buy Now** to be translated to Malay should be **Beli Sekarang**, not **Pay Now**.
4. When you change the `label` for the `style` object to `pay`, PayPal changes the main gold button label to `Pay with PayPal` and not `Buy with PayPal` anyway.

So the solution now is for the Malaysian payers to select **Malaysia** in order not to be confused by the button label when paying for non-merchandised items.